# Doctrine2 Mapping: 2 fields mapped to one field (ManyToOne)

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities, namely Match and Team. A Team can have one to many Matches. However, my Match entity consts of 2 fields which reference the same entity, Team. They are $homeTeam and $awayTeam. How do I reference the same field in Team, $matches, as a Bidirectional relationship?

My current non-working code is below:

My Match Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="match")
 **/
class Match {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team", inversedBy="matches")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="home_team_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * **/
    protected $homeTeam;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Team", inversedBy="matches")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="away_team_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * **/
    protected $awayTeam;
```

My Team Entity (incorrect I would presume?):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="team")
 * **/
class Team {

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Match", mappedBy="homeTeam", mappedBy="awayTeam") **/
    protected $matches;
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but you need to join with OR condition: homeTeam OR AwayTeam, as in my case i need to join with AND condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After exploring [Doctrine's official docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html): you can't add multiple `mappedBy` columns. Instead of this, you can choose between:

1. Create a custom repository for `Match` and define method `getAllMatchesForTeam($team)`
2. Define appropriate relations `$homeMatches` and `$awayMatches` + method `getAllMatches()` on `Team` and union results of `$homeMatches` and `$awayMatches` there

Read more here:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922047/symfony2-doctrine2-how-to-implement-methods-on-entity-to-retrieve-related-ent
2. [Custom repository class in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8148065/541961)
3. [Fetching data through a custom repository in a Twig extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450465/fetching-data-through-a-custom-repository-in-a-twig-extension)
4. [How can I access a service outside of a controller with Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124444/how-can-i-access-a-service-outside-of-a-controller-with-symfony2/6127711#6127711)